# what is the difference if we use the angular equivalent to jquery ajax

Tags: angularjs

I am newbie in using angular..I am just curious if there is difference in using the angular equivalent to jquery.ajax, is there difference in performance in requesting the data  to the server ?

Comment: There's no difference, except that the angular version fits better into angular. They both use wrappers for `xmlhttprequest`

Comment: There is a difference : angular will call $apply on rootScope after processing a $http response handlers, where $.get will not.

Answer (score 0):

The result is the same but when you are using the **$http** service when the request ends it is part of the angular environment and if you assign the return data to a variable (either $scoped or not) the $digest is automatic. When you do an AJAX request using an external library like jQuery for instance you should assign the data inside a **$timeout** function or using an **$applyAsync** like so:

```
function(response){
    $timeout(function(){
        $scope.myData = response.data;
    });
}

or

function(response){
    $scope.$applyAsync(function(){
        $scope.myData = response.data;
    });
}
```